# Getting coordinates of pixels which values are equal to 0

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-raster, landsat

I have a raster map with 202 rows and 201 columns
there are some grids in this map which pixel values is 0
I want to write a function that return all the pixel values 0 grids' coordinate
how can I do it
I was trying to use if loop and while loop
but it always says TRUE/FALSE need
here is my sample code

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(sp)


setwd("E:/Landsat-data-NASA atm-corrected/sample_day1")
restdir2 <- ("E:/Landsat-data-NASA atm-corrected/sample_day1")
  n3 <- list.files(restdir2, pattern="*band4_clip_1.tif", full.names=TRUE)
  n4 <- list.files(restdir2, pattern="*cloud_qa_clip_1.tif", full.names=TRUE)
  n5 <- list.files(restdir2, pattern="*cloud.tif", full.names=TRUE)

create<- function(x,y)
{
 layer <- raster(n4)
 layer2 <- raster(n3)
   for(c in 1:x)
  {
    for(r in 1:y)
   {      
       nl<- layer2
       if(layer[c,r]==0)
       return layer[c,r]
   }
  }
}
create (10,10)
```

Comment: We can't run any of your code without your data... maybe you could share data for a simple example? You should probably read an introduction to functions in R. `return()` returns an object and stops running the function... a function can only return one object. It's also a function, so you have to use parens with it. If you put it *inside* a for loop, the first time through the loop it will return and never get to the second time.

Comment: It's also pretty bad practice to use `c` as a variable, because `c()` is already the name of *the* most common R function.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two (very similar) approaches

```
library(raster)
# set up example data
r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
set.seed(0)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r)) * 10 - 5)

# approach 1, for a single layer
p <- rasterToPoints(r, fun=function(x){x == 0})

# approach 2, also works for multiple layers
# first remove all non zero cells
z <- subs(r, data.frame(0, 1))
p <- rasterToPoints(z)

# results
plot(r)
points(p[,1:2])
```

if you have multiple layers with the same spatial parameters (extent and resolution)

```
# create example data 
x1 <- setValues(r, round(runif(ncell(r)) * 10 - 5))
x2 <- setValues(r, round(runif(ncell(r)) * 10 - 5))
x3 <- setValues(r, round(runif(ncell(r)) * 10 - 5))

# combine layers
s <- stack(x1, x2, x3)

z <- subs(r, data.frame(0, 1))
p <- rasterToPoints(z)
```